# How to squeeze if not in list

Tags: python

The code below:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, myList):
        super(MyClass, self).__init__()
        self.myList = myList
    def getList(self):
        return self.myList

inst_list=[]
for i in range(3):
    inst_list.append(MyClass([1,2,3, None]))

result=[]
result+=[inst for inst in inst_list if inst.getList() for inst in inst.getList() if inst]

print result
```

results to:

```
[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
```

How to modify:

```
[inst for inst in isnt_list if inst.getList() for inst in inst.getList() if inst]
```

so it doesn't add a number if the number is already in a result list?

I've tried:

```
result+=[inst for inst in isnt_list if inst.getList() for inst in inst.getList() if (inst and not inst in result)]
```

but it didn't work for me.

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to achieve with your list comprehension; are you trying to only list unique elements? Why not just use `list(set(isnt_list))` then?

Comment: yes, I only need unique numbers in a result list

Comment: Preserving order or does order not matter?

Comment: The order does not matter. But would be nice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If order doesn't matter you want a *set*:

```
result = {v for inst in isnt_list for v in inst.getList()}
```

This uses a set comprehension to build a set object.

Comment: The numbers stored in a class attribute self.myList are going to be different. Only some of them will be overlapping. It just for this example to keep it simple I am assigning the same list to each class instance.

Comment: @Sputnix: so? This still produces only the unique values from those.

Comment: Great! Thanks!!! Your line is so short I thought you cut the corners assuming all the class instances are assigned the same value to self.myList attr. Pretty cool! Thanks again!